# python fcntl does not acquire lock

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, fcntl

I have written a code to write parallel in a csv file in python.
When my program gets over, what I see is that few lines are merged instead of in seperate lines. Each line should only contain 3 columns. But instead it shows as below

EG

```
 myname  myage  myvalue 
 myname  myage  myvaluemyname
 myname  myage  myvalue 
 myage
```

What I understood by reading few other questions, is that I need to lock my file if I want to avoid such scenarios. So I added fcntl module. But it seems my file is still not being locked as it produces similar output

My code

```
def getdata(x):
    try:
    # get data from API
        c.writefile(x,x1,x2)
except Exception,err:
    print err

class credits:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = dict()
        self.details = dict()
        self.filename = "abc.csv"
        self.fileopen = open(self.filename,"w")

    def acquire(self):
        fcntl.flock (self.fileopen, fcntl.LOCK_EX)

    def release(self):
        fcntl.flock(self.fileopen, fcntl.LOCK_UN)

    def __del__(self):
        self.fileopen.close()

    def writefile(self,x,x1,x2,x3):
        try:
            self.acquire()
            self.fileopen.write(str(x)+","+str(x1)+","+str(x2)+"\n")
        except Exception, e:
            raise e
        finally:
            self.release()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = psycopg2.connect()
    curr = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    curr.execute("select * from emp")
    rows = curr.fetchall()

    listdata = []
    for each in rows:
        listdata.append(each[0])

    c = credits()
    p = Pool(processes = 5)
    results = p.map(getdata,listdata)
    conn.close()
```

I had to declare getdata as TOP level function otherwise it gave me "Cant pickle function"

Comment: Did you disable the file buffer?

Comment: @denfromufa - I am sorry, but not sure if I understood you. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3168436/2230844

Comment: Ok. I did try adding 1 and 0 in fileopen command. But what I see in my file is pure garbage. I also tried adding flush command after write command. But it still shows me garbage

Comment: Next to write to file statement add equivalent print to console statement and see if they match

Comment: Print statement shows me correct values, which I added before write statement. But csv file shows me garbage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76514/discussion-between-neil-and-denfromufa).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/2230844

Comment: If that's not working then try queue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530258/2230844

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write to multiple files in each separate process and then merge them? It might be more computationally expensive but it will ensure thread safety.