# multiprocessing.Manager is limitting resources

Tags: python, io, multiprocessing

I am processing lot of data and writing them to file (large JSON).
I've implemented `multiprocessing` in order to use all of my cores. I would like to dump data to file while processing it, but it seems to be tricky in parallel processing. When I run my script without any storing (everything stays in memory) I can observe on resource indicator that whole CPU is used. That's fine.

When I use another process which is reading from `Manager().Queue()` ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file)) or if I append result to file in each process (protected with `Manager().Lock()` in blocking mode) CPU usage is equal to usage of one process. Changing number of workers doesn't make any difference.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
manager = mp.Manager()
queue = manager.Queue()
lock = manager.Lock()
# writer_job = pool.apply_async(writer, (queue, ))

# alternative way of creating processes
# jobs = []
# for s in sensors:
#     job = pool.apply_async(parseSensor, ([s, queue], ))
#     jobs.append(job)
#
# for job in jobs:
#     job.get()

# in the same way I am passing lock to processes
pool.map(parseSensor, zip(sensors, [queue] * len(sensors)))

# queue.put('kill')
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Is that expected behaviour?