# Queue using a function to write files not working when files have to be gzipped

Tags: python, gzip, python-multiprocessing

I switched from using `open` to `gzip.open` in some python code using `multiprocessing`, and files that weren't empty in the former version of the code now end up being empty. **Is this a known issue?** I'm unable to find information about similar problems on the internet.

My code is inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530258/1878788) except I use `imap_unordered` to set the workers to work instead of `apply_async` in a loop.

I'll try to make a minimum working example and add it to this post if necessary, but in case the problem is well known, I already give a verbal description of the situation:

I have a working python program in which computations are happening in a `multiprocessing.Pool` of workers using the pool's `imap_unordered` method.

These computations have to write data to some common files. This is achieved using communications through a `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue`. The worker functions take this queue as argument and send information to it using the queue's `put` method.

A "writer" function takes the queue as argument and a bunch of file paths, uses the paths to `open` files in `w` mode. Based on information received through the queue's `get` method, things are written to one of the files.

The "writer" function and its list of arguments are passed to the pool's `apply_async` method.

All this seems to work correctly, and I obtain files with things written inside.

Now I want to write this in a compressed form using gzip. I simply used `gzip.open` instead of `open`, and opened the files in `wb` mode. Apart from this and the fact that I added a ".gz" suffix to my file paths, everything is the same.

The program runs with no error messages, but I end up with empty file.

**Is the gzip module not usable with multiprocessing ?**

---

#### Edit: Code example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, cpu_count
import time
from gzip import open as gzopen

def writer(queue, path1, path2):
    with gzopen(path1, "wb") as f1, gzopen(path2, "wb") as f2:
        while True:
            (where, what) = queue.get()
            print("I'm a writer. I have to write:\n%s to %s" % (what, where))
            if where == "out1":
                f1.write(what)
            elif where == "out2":
                f2.write(what)
            else:
                print("flushing files")
                f1.flush()
                f2.flush()
            break

def do_divmod(num_and_queue):
    (num, queue) = num_and_queue
    q, r = divmod(num, 2)
    time.sleep(1)
    if r:
        queue.put(("out2", "q: %d\n" % q))
    else:
        queue.put(("out1", "q: %d\n" % q))
    time.sleep(1)
    return (num, q, r)

def main():
    with Manager() as mgr, Pool(processes=cpu_count() - 2) as pool:
        write_queue = mgr.Queue()
        pool.apply_async(writer, (write_queue, "/tmp/out1.txt.gz", "/tmp/out2.txt.gz"))
        for (n, q, r) in pool.imap_unordered(
            do_divmod,
            ((number, write_queue) for number in range(25))):
            print("%d %% 2 = %d" % (n, r))
            print("%d / 2 = %d" % (n, q))
        write_queue.put(("", ""))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Running the above code results in empty `/tmp/out1.txt.gz` and `/tmp/out2.txt.gz`.

I have to say that I'm having trouble getting the non-gzip version to work as well: In both cases, the `print("I'm a writer. I have to write:\n%s to %s" % (what, where))` seems to be executed only once:

```
$ ./test_multiprocessing.py 
I'm a writer. I have to write:
q: 0
 to out2
1 % 2 = 1
1 / 2 = 0
10 % 2 = 0
10 / 2 = 5
3 % 2 = 1
3 / 2 = 1
6 % 2 = 0
6 / 2 = 3
7 % 2 = 1
7 / 2 = 3
4 % 2 = 0
4 / 2 = 2
5 % 2 = 1
5 / 2 = 2
0 % 2 = 0
0 / 2 = 0
11 % 2 = 1
11 / 2 = 5
8 % 2 = 0
8 / 2 = 4
12 % 2 = 0
12 / 2 = 6
9 % 2 = 1
9 / 2 = 4
2 % 2 = 0
2 / 2 = 1
13 % 2 = 1
13 / 2 = 6
14 % 2 = 0
14 / 2 = 7
15 % 2 = 1
15 / 2 = 7
16 % 2 = 0
16 / 2 = 8
17 % 2 = 1
17 / 2 = 8
18 % 2 = 0
18 / 2 = 9
19 % 2 = 1
19 / 2 = 9
20 % 2 = 0
20 / 2 = 10
21 % 2 = 1
21 / 2 = 10
22 % 2 = 0
22 / 2 = 11
23 % 2 = 1
23 / 2 = 11
24 % 2 = 0
24 / 2 = 12
```

But at least, when the non-gzip version says it is writing something to a file, there is something in the file.

Comment: Show us your code of what you described

Comment: @stovfl I added an example, but doing so I realized that my initial code may also have a (different) problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some modifications based on examples found in [the documentation of the multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). It seems that I somehow can force the gzipped files to get written by using the `get` method of the thing returned by `apply_async`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, cpu_count
import time
from gzip import open as gzopen

def writer(queue, path1, path2):
    with gzopen(path1, "wb") as f1, gzopen(path2, "wb") as f2:
        while True:
            (where, what) = queue.get()
            print("I'm a writer. I have to write:\n%s to %s" % (what, where))
            # The encode seems necessary when things are actually written
            # (not necessary with files obtained with the normal open)
            if where == "out1":
                f1.write(what.encode())
            elif where == "out2":
                f2.write(what.encode())
            else:
                print("flushing files")
                f1.flush()
                f2.flush()
            break

def do_divmod(num_and_queue):
    (num, queue) = num_and_queue
    q, r = divmod(num, 2)
    time.sleep(1)
    if r:
        queue.put(("out2", "q: %d\n" % q))
    else:
        queue.put(("out1", "q: %d\n" % q))
    time.sleep(1)
    return (num, q, r)

def main():
    with Manager() as mgr, Pool(processes=cpu_count() - 2) as pool:
        write_queue = mgr.Queue()
        # getting the "result object"
        writing = pool.apply_async(writer, (write_queue, "/tmp/out1.txt.gz", "/tmp/out2.txt.gz"))
        for (n, q, r) in pool.imap_unordered(
                do_divmod,
                ((number, write_queue) for number in range(25))):
            print("%d %% 2 = %d" % (n, r))
            print("%d / 2 = %d" % (n, q))
        write_queue.put(("", ""))
        # Magic command to force the writing of the gzipped files
        # (not necessary when files are obtained through normal open)
        writing.get(timeout=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I have no idea why this works, and what is actually the thing that `apply_async` returns. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) doesn't say more that this "returns a result object". More explanations are welcome.

**Note that the above code is still bugged**. It solves the initial problem of gzipped files being empty but not the problem of the writer apparently doing some write job only once.

---

#### Edit: Further tests

It turns out that getting the result of `pool.apply_async` and running `get` on it is actually not the only way to get the gzipped files written.
Changing `what` to `what.encode()` also forces the writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, cpu_count
import time
from gzip import open as gzopen

def writer(queue, path1, path2):
    with gzopen(path1, "wb") as f1, gzopen(path2, "wb") as f2:
        while True:
            (where, what) = queue.get()
            print("I'm a writer. I have to write:\n%s to %s" % (what, where))
            if where == "out1":
                # The encode method call seems to force the writing
                f1.write(what.encode())
                #f1.write(what)
            elif where == "out2":
                # The encode method call seems to force the writing
                f2.write(what.encode())
                #f2.write(what)
            else:
                print("flushing files")
                f1.flush()
                f2.flush()
            break

def do_divmod(num_and_queue):
    (num, queue) = num_and_queue
    q, r = divmod(num, 2)
    time.sleep(1)
    if r:
        queue.put(("out2", "q: %d\n" % q))
    else:
        queue.put(("out1", "q: %d\n" % q))
    time.sleep(1)
    return (num, q, r)

def main():
    with Manager() as mgr, Pool(processes=cpu_count() - 2) as pool:
        write_queue = mgr.Queue()
        #writing = pool.apply_async(writer, (write_queue, "/tmp/out1.txt.gz", "/tmp/out2.txt.gz"))
        pool.apply_async(writer, (write_queue, "/tmp/out1.txt.gz", "/tmp/out2.txt.gz"))
        for (n, q, r) in pool.imap_unordered(
            do_divmod,
            ((number, write_queue) for number in range(25))):
            print("%d %% 2 = %d" % (n, r))
            print("%d / 2 = %d" % (n, q))
        write_queue.put(("", ""))
        #writing.get(timeout=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I'm still clueless about what is happening...

Comment: `class multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult`

    The class of the result returned by `Pool.apply_async()` and `Pool.map_async()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult

Comment: @stovfl Thanks for the documentation. How is it that gzipped files in the `writer` function do not get written unless `get` is called, whereas normal files do?

Comment: `Compress.flush([mode])`
... pending input is processed, ... mode ..., defaulting to Z_FINISH. ...prevents compressing any more data. ... the compress() method cannot be called again; the only realistic action is to delete the object.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zlib.html#zlib.Compress.flush