# Trouble writing python output to file with multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have found some similar questions to mine on this forum but none that has helped with my specific problem (I'm fairly new to python so forgive me if I should've understood the answer from a different thread).  I am actually working with a fairly complicated python code, but to illustrate the problem I've having I have written a very minimal code that exhibits the same behavior:

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    log_output = open('log','w')

    def sum_square(number):
        s = 0
        for i in range(number):
            s += i * i
        log_output.write(str(s)+'\n')
        return s

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        numbers = range(5)
        p = Pool()
        result = p.map(sum_square,numbers)

        p.close()
        p.join()
```

When this code is executed, there are no errors or warnings, etc., but the resulting file "log" is always totally empty.  This is the same behavior I find in my other more complicated python program also using a multiprocessing pool.  I had expected that the processes would probably print to file in the wrong order, but I'm confused why nothing prints at all.  If I get rid of the multiprocessing and just run the same basic code with a single process, it prints to file just fine.  Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing safely writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're well into undefined territory here, but just `flush`ing the file works for me. for example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

log_output = open('log', 'w')

def sum_square(number):
    print(number, file=log_output)
    log_output.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(sum_square, range(5))
```

works for me in Python 3.8 under Linux.  I've also shortened your code to clarify the issue, and make it slightly more idiomatic.