# Initializing multiprocessing manager immediately returns EOFError when numpy imported

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have been trying to figure out multiprocessing on python to run some code. I was playing with the code provided in the answer to [this stack exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file) which runs on my machine with no problems. However, when I include the line `import numpy as np`, as shown below, I get an `EOFError` at the line `manager = mp.Manager()`. Anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

import numpy as np
fn = 'test_out.json'

def worker(arg, q):
    '''stupidly simulates long running process'''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    s = 'this is a test'
    txt = s
    for i in range(200000):
        txt += s 
    done = time.perf_counter() - start
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        size = len(f.read())
    res = 'Process' + str(arg), str(size), done
    q.put(res)
    return res

def listener(q):
    '''listens for messages on the q, writes to file. '''

    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        while 1:
            m = q.get()
            if m == 'kill':
                f.write('killed')
                break
            f.write(str(m) + '\n')
            f.flush()

def main():
    #must use Manager queue here, or will not work
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()    
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() + 2)

    #put listener to work first
    watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

    #fire off workers
    jobs = []
    for i in range(80):
        job = pool.apply_async(worker, (i, q))
        jobs.append(job)

    # collect results from the workers through the pool result queue
    for job in jobs: 
        job.get()

    #now we are done, kill the listener
    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I was expecting no difference in the output given that the code does not ever even use any of the numpy processes. I have seen in a few other posts from years ago that Numpy can cause some multiprocessing issues but have not seen anything where it immediately causes the code to error out.

Comment: It works on my machine. What's your environment? OS, Python version, library versions...

Comment: macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, conda version : 23.11.0, conda-build version : 3.27.0, python version : 3.9.18.final.0, numpy 1.25.2

I am having some trouble finding the version of multiprocessing I am using as the package does not appear in conda lisa, but the file imports and runs multiprocessing fine.